# Less mixin and variables

Tags: less, less-mixins

I have the following mixin:

```
.iconFont(@color: @green, @font-size: 18px){
  color: @color;
  font-size: @font-size;
}
```

If I want only to change the second variable value, I need to write the first variable default value?

```
h1{
 .iconFont(@green, 14px);
}
```

Comment: @Harry, green is another variable (green: #f3b600). My question is: when h1 uses green (set as default in mixin), if I only set font-size value, this value goes to color.

Comment: Got you mate. It is not required if you make use of the named parameters feature offered by Less. Please refer to my answer for details on usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no need to specify the default value for the first parameter while calling the function. Instead you can just use [named parameters](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-named-parameters) feature to explicitly let the compiler know that the value you are passing in the mixin call is for the 2nd parameter.

```
.sample{
    .iconFont(@font-size:14px);
}
```

The above Less code when compiled would produce the below output. (Note: I had set the `@green` as `#00ff00`.)

```
.sample {
    color: #00ff00;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

---

While using the named parameter feature, even the order in which the parameters are passed does not matter. For example, the same mixin can be called as follows:

```
.sample2{
    .iconFont(@font-size:24px, @color: #070707);
}
```

And it would produce the below as output.

```
.sample2 {
    color: #070707;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```